# Widfly erases Mysql tables

Tags: java, mysql, wildfly

When starting  Wildfly server it erases all the tables of Mysql and recreates from scratch erasing all the data. How to fix that problem (erase the data) every time i need to reestart wildfly?

Thank you, I m using Hybernate

Following the Persistence

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
 <persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.1"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence 
 http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
 <persistence-unit name="casadocodigo-persistence-unit"
    transaction-type="JTA">
    <description>Forge Persistence Unit</description>
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>


    <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/casadocodigoDS</jta-data-source>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" 
         value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect" />
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: Are you using hibernate? If yes, there is a property which is responsible to delete and create database schema

Comment: Please, post your persistence.xml, there should be information about recreating the database there.

Comment: Tks Kamil and Jhenrique, I updated the question with the persistence.xml

Comment: Use a different value than `create-drop` for `<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
```

This are the options and explanations:

validate | update | create | create-drop

Validate = will validate the schema that you have, and makes no changes to the database.

Update = will update the database if the schema is already there in the database.

Create = will create new database, removing existing schema if any

Create-drop = will create new database and drops it when the sessionFactory is destroyed.